# Simple Serialize/Deserialize implementation

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, protobuf-net

I want to understand how to implement a Serialize/Deserialize without using the framework 
XmlSerializer. the serialization should support graphs.
I came across [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which looks like it does the trick but it's a very complex project and I got a little lost in it. I also found [NetSerializer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/351538/NetSerializer-A-fast-simple-serializer-for-NET) but it doesn't look like it supports graphs.
is there a simpler project ?

Comment: Does the DataContractSerializer handle your issue since it does remember references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DataContractSerializer`, something like:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
class Foo
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public Foo Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Should work. For protobuf-net, something very similar should work:

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public Foo Parent { get; set; }
}
```

---

From comments:

> my question wasn't how to use it. it was how it's implemented from behind

To implement from scratch, what this basically involves is: when you see an object for the first time (typically using ***reference*** equality, not `Equals` / `GetHashCode` overrides or `==` overloads), you invent a new unique identifier. This identifier could be a `Guid`, a random number, or more simply... `1`, `2`, `3`, ... So when you see an object for the first time, you say "here's a new object, identity `1`, content {...}"; then whenever you see it *again*, you just say "reference `1`".

If you are targetting core .NET, you can use `ObjectIDGenerator` for this:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var idgen = new ObjectIDGenerator();
        object foo = new object(), bar = new object(), blap = foo;
        Write(idgen, foo);
        Write(idgen, bar);
        Write(idgen, blap); // note this is the same object as foo
    }
    static void Write(ObjectIDGenerator idgen, object obj)
    {
        bool isNew;
        long id = idgen.GetId(obj, out isNew);
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", id, isNew);
    }
}
```

with output:

```
1, True
2, True
1, False
```

But because protobuf-net targets a range of platforms where this isn't always available, it implements this internally. As an implementation detail, for protobuf-net this is the `NetObjectCache.AddObjectKey` method (which should probably be called `GetObjectKey`, thinking about it). The exact way this is implemented depends on the target framework, but the *preferred* implementation is simply a `Dictionary<object,int>` using a custom comparer to ensure that the polymorphic `GetHashCode()` / `Equals` aren't used:

```
private sealed class ReferenceComparer : System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<object>
{
    public readonly static ReferenceComparer Default = new ReferenceComparer();
    private ReferenceComparer() {}

    bool System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<object>.Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return x == y; // ref equality
    }

    int System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<object>.GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

Then it is just a case of `TryGetValue` / `Add`, i.e.

```
if (!objectKeys.TryGetValue(value, out index)) index = -1;
...
if (!(existing = index >= 0))
{
    index = list.Add(value); // <=== creates a new identity
    ...
    objectKeys.Add(value, index); // <=== adds to the dictionary
}
```

Note that it gets *slightly* more complicated because protobuf-net treats strings differently - not as *references*, but as `string`s - to ensure that if two strings are identical in value, but are different string references, it uses the same reference and only stores the string once. By contrast, `BinaryFormatter` / `ObjectIdGenerator` makes the other choice here, to preserve reference identity on duplicated strings. You can see this in the previous code using:

```
Write(idgen, new string('a', 3));
Write(idgen, new string('a', 3));
```

For info, the details of writing the identity+payload vs reference are in `BclHelpers.WriteNetObject`, but note that this is implementation / format specific. But basically it uses a different numeric key to indicate "here's a new object / reference" to "re-use an existing object", via:

```
bool existing;
int objectKey = dest.NetCache.AddObjectKey(value, out existing);
ProtoWriter.WriteFieldHeader(existing
    ? FieldExistingObjectKey : FieldNewObjectKey, WireType.Variant, dest);
ProtoWriter.WriteInt32(objectKey, dest);
if (existing)
{
    writeObject = false;
}
```

and only writes the object *payload* for new objects.

Comment: hi Marc. my question wasn't how to use it. it was how it's implemented from behind, meaning the algorithm. the problem with protobuf-net is that it's extremely generic solution which involves thousands of lines of code and I got lost in trying to understand it.

Comment: @user1020742 is that enough detail?